# FileZilla to SSH into EC2 with Google Authenticator

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2, filezilla, google-authenticator

I have Foogle Authenticator setup on an AWS EC2 instance, so that, when I SSH in with my .pem file, I am prompted for the current security key.

I was wondering if it is possible to configure FileZilla to ask me for the security code, so that I can edit files on my AWS EC2 using FileZilla (instead of pure terminal).

FileZilla logs

```
2:17:23 Status:         Connecting to ec2-.....compute-  1.amazonaws.com...
12:17:23 Trace:         Going to execute   /Applications/FileZilla.app/Contents/MacOS/fzsftp
12:17:23 Response:  fzSftp started, protocol_version=8
12:17:23 Trace:         CSftpControlSocket::ConnectParseResponse(fzSftp    started, protocol_version=8)
12:17:23 Trace:         CSftpControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
12:17:23 Trace:         CSftpControlSocket::ConnectSend()
12:17:23 Command:   keyfile "/Users/.../...pem"
12:17:23 Trace:         CSftpControlSocket::ConnectParseResponse()
12:17:23 Trace:         CSftpControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
12:17:23 Trace:         CSftpControlSocket::ConnectSend()
12:17:23 Command:   open "ubuntu@......amazonaws.com" 22
12:17:24 Trace:         Server version: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.8
12:17:24 Trace:         We believe remote version has SSH-2 channel request bug
12:17:24 Trace:         Using SSH protocol version 2
12:17:24 Trace:         Doing ECDH key exchange with curve Curve25519 and hash SHA-256
12:17:25 Trace:         Server also has ... host keys, but we don't know any of them
12:17:25 Trace:         Host key fingerprint is:
12:17:25 Trace:         ssh- :...    uDt....=
12:17:25 Trace:         Initialised AES-256 GCM client->server encryption
12:17:25 Trace:         Initialised AES256 GCM client->server MAC algorithm  (in ETM mode) (required by cipher)
12:17:25 Trace:         Initialised AES-256 GCM server->client encryption
12:17:25 Trace:         Initialised AES256 GCM server->client MAC algorithm (in ETM mode) (required by cipher)
12:17:25 Trace:         Pageant is running. Requesting keys.
12:17:25 Trace:         Pageant has 0 SSH-2 keys
12:17:25 Trace:         Successfully loaded 1 key pair from file
12:17:25 Trace:         Offered public key from "/Users/.../....pem"
12:17:25 Trace:         Offer of public key accepted, trying to authenticate using it.
12:17:25 Trace:         Further authentication required
12:17:25 Trace:         Attempting keyboard-interactive authentication
12:17:25 Trace:         Using keyboard-interactive authentication. inst_len: 0, num_prompts: 1
12:17:25 Command:   Pass: 
12:17:25 Trace:         Keyboard-interactive authentication failed
12:17:25 Trace:         Attempting keyboard-interactive authentication
12:17:25 Trace:         Using keyboard-interactive authentication. inst_len: 0, num_prompts: 1
12:17:25 Error:         Authentication failed.
12:17:25 Trace:         CControlSocket::DoClose(1030)
12:17:25 Trace:         CSftpControlSocket::ResetOperation(1094)
12:17:25 Trace:         CControlSocket::ResetOperation(1094)
12:17:25 Error:         Critical error: Could not connect to server
12:17:25 Trace:         CFileZillaEnginePrivate::ResetOperation(1094)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to select *Interactive* for *"Logon Type"* on FileZilla Site Manager.

Comment: Wow! That worked without the .pem file! How's that possible?

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing the log file.